# Nzec error on codechef despite putting a return 0

Tags: c

I've written the following code for a codechef problem. Everytime I submit I get a NZEC error. Any ideas?

```
       #include<stdio.h>
       int main()
       {

           int n=0,s=0;
           int a[2001][2001]={0},i=0,k=0,c=0;
           scanf("%d%d",&n,&s);
           for(i=0;i<s;i++)
           {
                scanf("%d",&c);
                for(k=0;k<c;k++)
                {
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][k]);
                }
           }
           printf("%d\n",s);
           for(i=0;i<s;i++)
                printf("%d\n",i); 
           return 0;
        }
```

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/problems/FAULT/ is the question.

Comment: The problem should generally appear in the question itself (not just a link to it), preferably in a summarised form. You should also say what an NZEC error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array is created in the stack, which might be too small for it.

Essentially in multi-threaded applications, each thread will have its own stack. But, all the different threads will share the heap.

So in your `int main()` function when you define the array you are actually creating it in the stack (it's the "main thread"). If you move it outside of the function and define it globally, it will be created in the heap.
*(This is a bit more complicated than what I've just described, e.g. if you create an object using the `new` keyword inside a function it will be created in the heap etc. but I won't be explaining that now)*

You can check the stack size by using `ulimit -s`.

Also note that the stack is generally faster than the heap because of the way memory is allocated.

Answer (score 2):

`int a[2001][2001]` is too large for stack, declare it as a global variable.

```
int a[2001][2001]={0};
int main()
{
    int n=0,s=0;
    int i=0,k=0,c=0;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&s);
    /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks.What is the upper limit of the size of the local array? and i dont understand why global variables can be bigger..

Comment: The stack size can be obtained (and modified) by typing: `ulimit -s`. But, the heap size is much bigger (and making this variable "global" move it to the heap).

Comment: @user1614476 Local arrays are stored in **system stack**, and global arrays are stored in **system heap**. The size of system stack is implement-specified, but it's usually smaller than system heap.

Comment: @perror The stack size cannot be obtainedand or modified in an online test.

Comment: @user1614476: You should mark the answer as "correct", as it answer properly to your question.

Comment: @user1614476 Uh... You got me. I guess they're kept separately because they have different lifetime.